# sed text substitution error

Tags: linux, terminal

I am trying substitute text in a file with a value in a variable using `sed`:

```
file=1601001000100000003_0003_0_E_2011-11-21_16-52-16.db

sed -i "s/yyyy/$file" tempsbchg.sh
```

but `sed` returns:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unterminated `s' command
```

I have also tried:

```
sed -i "s/yyyy/${file}" tempsbchg.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last `/`.

Try:

```
sed -i "s/yyyy/$file/" tempsbchg.sh
```

The syntax of the *s* (as in substitute) command is *‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’*. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given *s* command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the *regexp or replacement* only if it is preceded by a \ character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "terminate" the substitution -- put a `/` at the end of it:

```
file=1601001000100000003_0003_0_E_2011-11-21_16-52-16.db

sed -i "s/yyyy/$file/" tempsbchg.sh
```